# VBA interacting with Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an Excel VBA code adapting my need, but I am not able to tell the code how to click on the example that I put in the attachment. The reference you have in Internet Explorer is this

```html
<a href="/siconv/ConsultProposal/ProfileQueryProfileQueryProposal.of?id?proposed=1336163&destino=&idConvenio=">
```

and I'm not sure how to put this prompt for VBA to click. Anyone who can help thanks, Nilton.

```
Sub lsConsultaObjetoPropostaSiconv()
'Inclui a referência se não houver
lReferenciaIE

Dim IE                  As InternetExplorer
Dim lProposta           As String
Dim lUltimaLinhaAtiva   As Long
Dim lContador           As Long

'Identifica a última célula ativa da lista
lUltimaLinhaAtiva = Worksheets("Plan4").Cells(Worksheets("Plan4").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Cria um objeto Internet Explorer
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

'Torna o objeto visível
IE.Visible = True

'Faz um loop por todas as linhas da planilha
For lContador = 2 To lUltimaLinhaAtiva
    'Navega ao site Siconv
    IE.Navigate "https://www.convenios.gov.br/siconv/proposta/ConsultarProposta/ConsultarProposta.do"

    'Identifica se a página já foi totalmente carregada
    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend

    'Como a página possui JavaScript que cria os objetos que são preenchidos após a carga completa, é necessário
    'aguardar um tempo, coloquei 3 segundos, alterar conforme a necessidade.
    'Caso não tenha javascript na criação dos objetos da página comentar esta parte do código, pois será bem
    'mais rápida a execução.
    sng = Timer
    Do While sng + 3 > Timer
    Loop

    'Carrega os dados da proposta que serão preenchidos na página
    lProposta = Range("A" & lContador).Value

    'Carrega os dados da proposta na página e submete os dados do formulário
    IE.Document.all("numeroProposta").innertext = lProposta
    IE.Document.forms("consultarPropostaPreenchaOsDadosDaConsultaConsultarForm").submit

    'Identifica se a página já foi totalmente carregada
    While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend

    Clica no número da proposta e abre nova aba        
    'IE.Document.body.getElementsByTagName ("Número da Proposta")
    'IE.Document.getElementById("a").Click

     'Como a página possui JavaScript que cria os objetos que são preenchidos após a carga completa, é necessário
    'aguardar um tempo, coloquei 3 segundos, alterar conforme a necessidade.
    'Caso não tenha javascript na criação dos objetos da página comentar esta parte do código, pois será bem
    'mais rápida a execução.
    sng = Timer
    Do While sng + 3 > Timer
    Loop

    'Faz um loop pelos objetos do tipo table na página e procura pelo campo Objeto do Convênio.
    'Em seguida busca pela segunda coluna da linha de Situação e armazena esta informação diretamente na coluna B da linha da planilha
    For Each i In IE.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("table")
        If InStr(i.innertext, "Objeto do Convênio") > 0 Then
            For Each l In i.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                If InStr(l.innertext, lProposta) Then
                    Range("B" & lContador).Value = l.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext 
                End If
            Next l
        End If
    Next i
Next lContador

MsgBox "Concluído!"
```

End Sub

[Internet Explorer Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FK2l.png)

Comment: Please specify URL and share VBA code you have, check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: omegastripes I'm sorry I put the code that I'm adapting for my use.